# Import data from csv in django - Has_header attribute doesnt ignore the first line

Tags: django, csv

I have to create an application that imports datas from a csv into a django model that already exists. I used the django-adaptator tool that allows to do that easily.

For exemple, I have a Sates (= "Pays") model that contains 3 fields : name, code, and nationality.

My csv :

```
nom;abrev;nationalite
AFGHANISTAN;AF;Afghane
AFRIQUE DU SUD;ZA;Sud-africaine
```

Here is my code

Models.py that already exists :

```
class Pays(models.Model):
pays = models.CharField(max_length=150)
codeiso3166alpha2 = models.CharField(max_length=2)
nationalite = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
maj = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
class Meta:
    db_table = u'Pays'
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.pays
```

Models.py from my application :

```
# coding: utf-8
from django.db import models
from polyc2n.models import Pays #the model that already exists
from adaptor.model import CsvDbModel

class MyCSVDbModel(CsvDbModel):

    class Meta:
        exclude = ['maj']
        dbModel = Pays
        delimiter = ";"
        has_header = True
        update = {'keys': ['codeiso3166alpha2']}
```

My views.py:

```
# coding: utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
from remplirPays.models import MyCSVDbModel
from django.http import HttpResponse

path = "pays.csv"

def DataPays(request):
    MyCSVDbModel.import_data(data = open(path))
    return HttpResponse("import is ok")
```

Here is my problem : when I do the import, the first line isn't ignored, even if I set the "has_header" attribute at True. Do you guys know why or do you know how can I resolve my problem ?

Thank you for reading

Comment: About which bit are you talking ?
That's the " has_header = True" from my models.py that doesn't work

Comment: what do you call a bit ?
I have nothing more than those codes + the csv

Comment: I didn't understand your sentence
Actually, the line "has_header = True" has to ignore the first line of my csv (i.e nom;abrev;nationalite). So this line should not be imported into my database.
The problem is that this line isn't ignored and figures in my database

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you better try using datareader and a load.py file, here i gave you a example code i use :

```
import csv,sys,os
import django

pathproject = "/home/yourfolder"
base_csv_filepath = "/home/yourfolder/yourcsvfile"
sys.path.append(pathproject)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'config.settings.local'
django.setup()

from yourapp.models import yourmodel

def load_your_data():
    print ("Entering...")
    csv_file = base_csv_filepath + "/yourcsvfile.csv"
    dataReader = csv.reader(open(csv_file, encoding='utf-8'),delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
    for row in dataReader:
        if row[0] != 'ID':
            yourmodel.objects.create(
                field1=row[0],
                field2=row[1]
            )
    print ("Imported correctly")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_your_data()
```

**EDIT:**  'ID' would be the header column text, and assuming it's a 2 row data, you can of course modifiy it as you wish to cover bigger parameters.